# What's the name for a class that simply contains mixins?

Tags: terminology, naming-conventions, nomenclature, class-names

Is there a name for a class that simply acts as a holder for mixins?

A simple example in C++ would look like this:

```
template<typename... Mixins>
class WhatsMyName : Mixins... {
};
```

WhatsMyName doesn't have any functionality of its own, and is just a proxy for the mixins that it contains.

Container and Holder seem too generic, MixingBowl is too cute, and Cone is too obscure. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Case, or Armor.  Or if you want to be cute, a Katamari.

Comment: I think you can only call it a Katamari if you mix in *every* class you have.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a regular class. Mixins are an implementation detail and should have no effect on the naming. It should be named for what it does, not what it contains.

Comment: But in this case the class doesn't even hold any mixins, it's just a template that could hold mixins. It has no purpose outside of containing mixins.